# Secret key generation in the BGV scheme in HElib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, key-generation, ring-lwe

This question is about secret key generation, based on section 4.7 in the design document:
https://homenc.github.io/HElib/documentation/Design_Document/HElib-design.pdf

It seems that if $m$ is not a power of two, then we choose coefficients of the secret key such that the secret key is a polynomial of degree $m$. How is it reduced into a polynomial of degree $\phi(m)$? If we just reduce mod $\Phi_m(X)$ then the coefficients may be outside $\{-1,1\}$, so I assume based on the way it is written that there is some other method.

Comment: Considering [HElib's code](https://github.com/homenc/HElib/blob/master/src/sample.cpp#L236), it seems that they really just reduce the polynomial modulo $\Phi_m(X)$.

Comment: But then the secret key has coefficients outside $\{-1,1\}$. Is this okay with the probability analysis they mention?